# JQuery drag drop items and get its value to use it for search

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

First of all I'm not familiar with jQuery or JavaScript, I only know PHP very well

I followed a [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Fsw8LVpkFU), but I didn't get the expected result.

What I need is to create a box to drop some images , and when an image dropped in that box I get the title of the image , so I can use that title value in a search (using the box as search area)

I started with the mentioned tutorial, which is:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag Drop using Jquery</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="jquery.js"/></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="item"><img src="banana.png" title="banana" alt="banana" /></li>
            <li class="item"><img src="spinach.png" title="spinach" alt="spinach" /></li>
            <li class="item"><img src="cumin.png" title="cumin" alt="cumin" /></li>
            <li class="item"><img src="mango.png" title="mango" alt="mango" /></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    padding:0;
    width: 500px;
    list-style:none;
}
.item{
    cursor:pointer;
}

#list{
    border:1px solid #000000;   width:100px; height:150px; background:#f0f0f0;
}
#list .border{
    background:red;
    border-width:2px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').draggable({containment: "document", revert:true,
        start: function(){
            contents = $(this).title();
        }
    });

    $('#list').droppable({hoverClass: 'border', accept: '.item',
        drop: function(){
            $('#list').append(contents = '&nbsp;');
        }
    });

})
```

---

Thank you very much for answering my question

Just I wanna:
1- know how to avoid repeating any `attr('title')` which added before ?

2- Also if I add any `attr('title')` by mistake how to delete it ?

Comment: So we have to code it for you using 'jQuery of Java'?

Comment: Just I need only a key so I can do all my self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `.title()` method, that means if you want to get the title you have to use `.attr()`. Secondly you are selecting a *li* which actually has no *title* attribute, so you have to select the *image* instead.

You also need to declare *contents* outside the *draggable* function, otherwise it will only work there.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var contents = '';
    $('li img').draggable({
        containment: "document",
        revert: true,
        start: function () {
             contents = $(this).attr('title');
        }
    });

    $('#list').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'border',
        accept: 'img',
        drop: function () {
            $('#list').append(contents + '&nbsp;');
        }
    });
})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/sTGs6/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Spokey I just wonder, what was the problem with my code other than attr('title') because from the beginning `accept:` wasn't working at all with me

Comment: @usamasulaiman Any error in javascript will stop execution code if error not handled, so this is already a sufficient reason

Comment: As roasted said, if you would have looked in the developer console (or firebug or whatever) you would have seen a javascript error (something something has no method .title()). This error will prevent any script to run any further on the page

Comment: :) I know , same as PHP, just I tried many simple `accept` methods but items wasn't items stuck to the box

Comment: @usamasulaiman `revert: true,` makes the items go back and not stay in the box.

Comment: by the way , what if I need to avoid repeating of items, so the item can drop only one time

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/sTGs6/1/ this will allow only one item of the same kind. It basically adds the class boxed to the items that were placed inside the box. Then the accept method does not allow the class boxed so you can't place more of those. From here on you have to work on the delete function

Answer (score 2):

You're calling

```
contents = $(this).title();
```

jQuery has no .title() method - try using [.attr('title');](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead

Answer (score 2):

You are dragging the li element which don't has a title attribute. To get the title attribute of the image wrapped by the li you can do :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contents;
    $('li').draggable({containment: "document", revert:true,
        start: function(){
            contents = $(this).find('img').attr('title');
        }
    });
});
```